# Mongoengine + Django: strange errors with fields during rendering

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I use Mongoengine 0.8.7 + Django 1.6.5, Mongodb 2.7
I have model

```
class Tweet(DynamicDocument):
#user = ReferenceField(User, reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE)
#id = StringField(db_field='id',required=True)
text = StringField(db_field='text', required=True)
lang = StringField(db_field='lang', max_length=200)
slug = StringField(db_field='slug', max_length=200)
retweeted = BooleanField()
#retweet_count = IntField()
text_length = IntField()
date_modified = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
is_published = BooleanField(default=True)
tags = ListField(ReferenceField(Tag))

#meta = {'allow_inheritance': False}

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.text

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.text_length = len(self.text)
    return super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post-detail', args=[self.id])

def get_edit_url(self):
    return reverse('post-update', args=[self.id])

def get_delete_url(self):
    return reverse('post-delete', args=[self.id])
```

View in views.py:

```
class TweetListView(ListView):
    model = Tweet
    context_object_name = "tweet_list"

    def get_template_names(self):
        return ["blog/tweet_list.html"]

    def get_queryset(self):
        tweets = Post.objects
        if 'all_posts' not in self.request.GET:
            tweets = tweets.filter(text__startswith='RT')
        tag = self.request.GET.get('tag', None)
        if tag:
            tweets = tweets.filter(tags=tag)

        #if not tag:
        #    tweets = tweets.filter(retweeted=True)
        return tweets
```

And template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% for tweet in tweet_list %}
        <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                <h4>tweet.id: {{ tweet.id }}</h4>
            {{ tweet.text|linebreaks }}
                        tweet.retweeted: {{ tweet.retweeted }}
            tweet.created_at: {{ tweet.created_at }}

            {% if tweet.tags %}
            Tags:
            <ul>
                {% for tag in tweet.tags %}
                    <li><a href="?tag={{ tag.id }}">{{ tag }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>           
               {% endif %}
        </br>
            <a href="{{ tweet.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-small">Read</a>
            <a href="{{ tweet.get_edit_url }}" class="btn btn-small">Edit</a>
            <a href="{{ tweet.get_delete_url }}" class="btn btn-small">Delete</a>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

All works fine and tweets showed in browser while in view i use filter   `is_published=True`  but if i change to some another it starts to throw errors:
For example i use:  text__startswith='RT'  (field text), result:

```
Exception Value:    

id must be an instance of (str, unicode, ObjectId), not <type 'dict'>

Exception Location:     D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\bson\objectid.py in __validate, line 203
```

If i change to `tweets.filter(slug__startswith='RT')`   result:

```
Exception Value:    

Cannot resolve field "slug"

Exception Location:     build\bdist.win32\egg\mongoengine\queryset\transform.py in query, line 60
```

I mined tweets with external script and now want to use Flask to query existing collection to show tweets in web interface. And i don't want to define all tweet structure in ORM.

I have Robomongo and i see manually added from admin posts near the tweets, mined by Twitter python library. Fields are named "text" and "lang" because in tweet JSON they are named the same.
Why any other field doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Found answer myself:

in views.py i changed `tweets = Post.objects`  to  `tweets = Tweet.objects` - that was was main mistake to use upper model that doesn't have fields i need to query

Then i renamed collection to `tweets` - and now my queries works, and no _cls dependance